$T_0$ topological groups and countable pseudocharacter
I know that topological groups are completely regular. So, if a topological group is $T_0$, then it is $T_1$, and the pseudocharacter would be defined for the space. I was wondering about $T_0$ topological groups that don't have countable pseudocharacter, but I haven't found any. So, I wanted to ask for an example of such, or if $T_0$ topological groups have countable pseudocharacter.
In $\pi$-Base there are a few examples of spaces with some of the involved properties pending to be determined, and verifying the rest. Here, there are the lists of those spaces where just one property is pending to be determined:
List $1$: ?Countable pseudocharacter. Note that the weak topology on a separable Hilbert space is cosmic (in $\pi$-Base it is missing that it has a countable network, but it is in the process to be added; see here instead meanwhile), so it has countable pseudocharacter, and it would be out of the list.
List $2$: ?Topological group.

How do you define pseudocharacter in non-$T_1$ spaces?

Not sure, does this already answer one of your questions:
${0,1}^{\omega_1}$ is a $T_2$ compact, topological group of uncountable pseudocharacter.

If a space isn't $T_1$, then there exists at least a point in the space that isn't an intersection of open sets of the space.

Yeah, that answers my question. Continuum power of a countable discrete space (from list $1$) would be another example.

I didn't know that having a group topology is a productive property.

And it isn't hereditary, checking the unit interval.

Well, according to your comment, you also define pseudocharacter for $T_1$ spaces, only. But then I don't understand your question, "I was wondering about $T_0$ topological spaces that don't have countable pseudocharacter".

My bad! I wanted to write groups. Thank you so much for pointing it out, and for your patience.

Thank you so much for your answer aswell. You already answered my question back then. Feel free to make it an answer instead of a comment too if you want.

Ulli answered the question in the comments providing the example of a compact $T_2$ space that has a group topology and that doesn't have countable pseudocharacter.
Consider $\{0, 1\}$ with the discrete topology. Since $\{0, 1\}$ is compact, $T_2$ and has a group topology, and these properties are productive, then $X = \{0, 1\}^{\omega_1}$ with the product topology is also compact, $T_2$ and has a group topology.
However, $X$ doesn't have countable pseudocharacter. Here is my attempt to prove it:
Let $i \in \omega_1$, define $p_i : X \rightarrow \{0, 1\}; (x_j)_{j\in\omega_1} \mapsto x_i$.
Let $x = (x_i)_{i\in\omega_1} \in X$.
We have that $\mathcal{B} = \{p_i^{-1}(x_i) : i \in \omega_1\}$ is a subbase of neighborhoods of $x$.
Let $I$ be a countable subset of $\omega_1$, define $\mathcal{A} = \{p_i^{-1}(x_i) : i \in I\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$.
As $\omega_1$ is uncountable, we have that $\{x\} \subsetneq \bigcap\mathcal{A} = \Pi_{i \in \omega_1}A_i$, where $A_i = \{0, 1\}$ if $i \in (\omega_1 \setminus I) \neq \emptyset$, and $A_i = \{x_i\}$ if $i \in I$.
As $\mathcal{A}$ is an arbitrary countable subset of $\mathcal{B}$, then $X$ doesn't have countable pseudocharacter.
